# Power BI DAX data from 2 tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgstm.jpg)

And I want to get total revenue for Store ABC only for product "ID1" so in this simple tables the final Revenue should be 251.

So I should filter only "ABC" in first table and filter only "ID1" in the second and then add column "Revenue" to the first table with the key "email" and then SUM revenue, but I got completely lost how to write it in DAX

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: You can merge Table1 (left) and Table2 (right) using email column. Then use Measures to calculate Revenue for specific store and product.

Comment: You mean merge in Power Query? thats I keep as the last option :) Because 1 email can be in more stores, have more products IDs etc so I was hoping to calculate it directly with DAX for more stores+product combinations

Comment: Then just post sample data covering all scenario. Also add your expected output from the sample data.